# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial:

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.kira03.contacts_extract">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
</manifest>
```

this is my manifest file.... eventhough i gave permissions my app is not launching this is the folllowing logcatthis is my manifest file.... eventhough i gave permissions my app is not launching this is the folllowing logcat

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                        Process: com.example.kira03.contacts_extract, PID: 19171
>                                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.kira03.contacts_extract/com.example.kira03.contacts_extract.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
>   com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from
>   ProcessRecord{51623c9
>   19171:com.example.kira03.contacts_extract/u0a144} (pid=19171,
>   uid=10144) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or
>   android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening
>   provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from
>   ProcessRecord{51623c9
>   19171:com.example.kira03.contacts_extract/u0a144} (pid=19171,
>   uid=10144) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or
>   android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
>                                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3572)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4827)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2062)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1473)
>                                                                                            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:477)
>                                                                                            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:435)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.example.kira03.contacts_extract.MainActivity.extract(MainActivity.java:27)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.example.kira03.contacts_extract.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: You are testing it on which OS version?

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. Describe any and all relevant information. The `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial` indicates this is being executed on `Lollipop 5.0 API level 21` or at least over API 19 (KitKat).l If this is true, there are many tutorials, even on [Developer Google, on how to request permissions during runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Looks like you're testing on android 6.0 and certain permissions have to be handled at runtime in 6.0. Check how to do that here https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this in 6.0 version,

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
        {
            // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
             if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this,
                     Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
             != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

         // Should we show an explanation?
         if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SplashScreen.this,
                 Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {

             // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
             // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
             // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

         } else {

             // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

             ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashScreen.this,
                     new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                     MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);

             // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
             // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
             // result of the request.
         }
     }
     else
     {
                 Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, EmtyActivity.class);
                 startActivity(i);

                 // close this activity
                 finish();

     }
```